# file name completion in .gitignore

Tags: autocompletion, git

I often "unignore" files in `.gitignore`, like this:

```
*
!.gitignore
!file.txt
!dir
!dir/*
```

Can I modify the pattern for which insert mode file name completion would work? In this case, instead of `./` I'd like the exclamation mark to suffice. I know [this qustion on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50041137/) sort of deals with the problem, but I'd like to know if there's a way without [`omnifunc`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Omni_completion).

```
NVIM v0.3.2-964-g7e97587da
Linux 4.20.0-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Dec 24 03:00:40 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3):

how do you trigger file-name completion.
completing with `^X^F` should do it if '!' does not show up in `set isfname?`

Comment: My question was incomplete, sorry. It does work.

Comment: I use Lifepillar's mucomplete with the variable `let g:mucomplete#chains.gitignore = ['file']` and would have expected the completion to work just like `^X^F` (where gitignore is a filetype). In my list of todo's I wrongly noted that the manual file completion did not work in this context. I could've just remapped tab locally to `^X^F`. But I like mucomplete's custom `path` completion which I'd like to use, but I can't get it to work without a `./` prefix.

Comment: thanks for the `isfname` tip, but it wasn't the issue. I got it to work with mucomplete which required adding `!` to `iskeyword` and a `can_complete` variable (see this issue https://github.com/lifepillar/vim-mucomplete/issues/127)